# Is this a correct addition to a pipe friction loss calculation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, friction, units, unit-conversion

I've been using this online calculator to work out the difference in pressure and flow between two ends of a pipe:

[Pipe Friction Calculation for Fluid Flow in a Pipe](http://www.efunda.com/formulae/fluids/calc_pipe_friction.cfm)

So far most of it makes sense, and I've managed to figure out the worst of it (pipe relative roughness >_<). The main problem is that we don't have the "Average fluid velocity in pipe $\mathrm{V}$", only the Flow at A in $\mathrm{l}/\mathrm{s}$.

Before you mock the next part I should explain that I'm a software developer, which apparently still qualifies me more for this sort of work than my water engineer brother-in-law...

Anyway, to convert from Flow to Velocity, I made up the following:

```
L: litres per second at A
D: diameter of pipe (m)
V: fluid velocity (in m/s)
```

$$V = \frac{ 1000L }{ \pi(D/2)^2 } $$

Is this the correct conversion, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volumetric flow $\Phi = A V$.  Therefore the right expression would be

$$V = \frac{ L/1000 }{ \pi(D/2)^2 }.$$

To get volumetric flow in SI units $\mathrm{m}^3/\mathrm{s}$ you should DIVIDE $\mathrm{l}/\mathrm{s}$ by 1000.

Comment: I had a feeling I'd missed something vital. Thanks.

Comment: Marko: We have MathJax active on the site so [you can typeset you mathematics using LaTeX alike notation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation). I'll do this one for you.

Comment: @dmckee: Fancy. I've fixed my question using your edits as a template.

Comment: @dmckee cool. and some characters to obtain 15