# Flow Rate Calculation from a drain tank through a pipe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, friction, flow, viscosity

I want to know how to calculate the flowrate (Q) of a drain tank flowing through a pipe (see the figure below)

All I know is that Q=Velocity(V) x Area (A)

V= sqrt(2*g*H)=sqrt(2*9.81*10)=14m/s.

I believe this is wrong since we are not considering the friction in the pipe.
How can i calculate the Exact Q of this problem. assuming the material of the pipe is known.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculation of pressure from flow rate of water](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127760/)

Comment: Hi Loris. The question I've linked isn't an obvious duplicate at first sight, but the answers to it explain how to calculate flow rates in a pipe given the pressure difference.

Comment: As for the part where you want to take into account the frictional loss, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/is-this-a-correct-addition-to-a-pipe-friction-loss-calculation?rq=1) and the link therein.

Comment: In case it's not clear, you have to break it into a few problems: 1) What is the resistance to flow at the orifice, and that depends strongly on the shape of the orifice, how it is tapered, etc. 2) What is the resistance to flow in the pipe. 3) If there are bends in the pipe, what is the resistance due to those? Those resistances all give pressure drop as a function of velocity, and you know the total pressure drop, so you have to solve for the velocity. From that you get the flow rate.